# Can I talk about my business in shul if it is to help another Jew avoid a transgression?

Tags: synagogue, kavod, shaatnez

Reuven's job is to check clothing for shaatnez and remove it. Shimon gives Reuven a suit to check. Later they meet in the synagogue.

[Mishna Berura 151 (1)[2]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=48) forbids even mundane talk for one's business in the synagogue.

Shimon wants to know if the shaatnez has been removed; this is not for his business – it is to avoid him doing something that is forbidden. What is involved in asking Reuven, whose business it is, if he has finished the suit? And  what is involved in Reuven responding?

Let us assume that the question does not come up in the three weeks.

A shaalah has been asked of a LOR.

Comment: What transgression would you be helping him avoid (e.g. not causing you distress by keeping your suit too long)? And why can't you talk to him afterwards outside of the synagogue?

Comment: @Fred Reuven helps Shimon avoid the issur of wearing shaatnez. And of course Shimon can ask Reuven outside. The question is whether this is a conversation that would be permitted in shul or **must** be had outside.

Comment: Reuven is holding the suit. How could Shimon wear it?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok If so, I find your title misleading, as the conversation about getting your suit back doesn't function to prevent someone from sinning.

Comment: I'm uncertain as to why the M.B. explains this as being business related, specifically, since the Mechaber makes a general statement. I.e., MB, doesn't seem to prove his point from what I can tell. As I understand, ALL mundane conversation is prohibited. As @Daniel states, Re'uven has the suit, now. No one is violating anything at the moment - no mitzvot or aveirot related to shatnez are being performed now. What does asking Re'uven about what he  did accomplish that can't wait until your out of shul? To me it sounds like an "idle" conversation. Different if you asked, "HOW did you check it?"

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about talking during davening, you can't.

As to talking business in schul not during davening, it would tend to be forbidden. However, the Ben ish chai writes that if one is a sefarim seller, he may do business in the schul as the schul is the natural gathering place of people who study torah. A shatnez checker is in a similar situation.

Comment: Reference to the Ben Ish Chai please?